# Oauth refresh token

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, openid-connect

Sorry for the newbie question.
What the point of refresh token if i have to send my credentials anyway?

Or in another words, what the practical difference between requesting refresh token or just a new access token?

here is my code:

```
    TokenResponse tokenResponse = null;
var tokenRequest = new TokenRequest
    {
        GrantType = "customgrant",
        ClientId = "myUserName",
        ClientSecret = "secret",
        Address = disco.TokenEndpoint,
    };

tokenResponse = await client.RequestTokenAsync(tokenRequest);

var testClient = new HttpClient();

testClient.SetBearerToken(tokenResponse.AccessToken);

var apiRes = await testClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:11000/api/GetData/104246");
if (!apiRes.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{

    if (apiRes.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
    {

        RefreshTokenRequest refreshTokenRequest = new RefreshTokenRequest();
        refreshTokenRequest.RefreshToken = tokenResponse.RefreshToken;
        refreshTokenRequest.ClientId = "myUserName";
        refreshTokenRequest.ClientSecret = "secret";
        refreshTokenRequest.Address = disco.TokenEndpoint;
        tokenResponse = await testClient.RequestRefreshTokenAsync(refreshTokenRequest);
    }
}
```

Comment: What flow are you using?

Comment: What credentials are you talking about? In a normal setup the _client_ doesn't know the _user's_ credentials, so it has to use the refresh token since there is no alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. `refresh token` is used to get new valid `access token` and you don't need user credentials, when you already have valid `refresh token`.

Comment: it's not true.
i'm using IdentityServer4 + .net core application, when i call RequestRefreshTokenAsync with RefreshToken parameter i'm getting "client_id is missing"

Comment: @OmriD sure, I can be wrong. Then doc of used IdP is a good start for you.

Comment: i didnt find any clear documentation on this issue.
dont get me wrong, i whould like to get your help.

Comment: @OmriD Yes it's true. Add your code to the question, seems you are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

when a token is generated, you first need the Auth code as parameter to pass it as request to token api. To generate the Auth code, you still have to call its api and it involves few manual steps for authorizing your app and the account. These manual steps can't be avoided and it creates hurdles while creating a smooth automation.

To avoid these manual steps, OAuth has a provision to generate new tokens using the refresh_token. You get refresh_token when you generate a token for the first time. Once you have the refresh_token, you can easily generate new tokens and use it in your subsequent api calls. The generated tokens expire in one hour but the refresh tokens don't expire if you use it once in 6 months to generate a token which I believe is a reasonable amount of time for us. Automation can be achieved through refresh token --> token --> API call, where no manual intervention is required. I hope this helps.

Thanks,
Raj